# How to use Implies and if boolean commands in z3 python API

Tags: python, python-2.7, z3

How to implement `if-then-else` using Z3 python API as a part of conjunction of first order formulas? e.g.

```
s.add( F, H, (if then else)).
```

A related question is: how to use Boolean "Implies" or "if" commands given in Z3 python online guide for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An expression `if(A, B, C)` in encoded in the Z3 Python API using `If(A, B, C)`.
Here is an example:

```
F, H, A, B, C = Bools('F H A B C')
s = Solver()
s.add(F, H, If(A, B, C))
print s
```

Here is another example using "implies"

```
F, H, A, B, C = Bools('F H A B C')
s = Solver()
s.add(F, H, Implies(A, B))
print s
```

The links for the examples above are: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/4BF, http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/JEU